# Assert Specific Word Exists Before Another Specific Word in a Lookahead

Tags: .net, regex

Consider the following string and the regex I am using on it:

```
start match the target if stop appears before the next start

(?<=start.*)target(?=.*stop)
```

I am matching the word `target` if it appears after the word `start` and before the word `stop`. However, I need to know how to modify the lookahead such that `target` is only matched if another occurrence of the word `start` does not appear between `target` and `stop`. For example, the following string should not result in a match:

```
start don't match the target if the next start appears before stop
```

It also needs to match if there is a following `stop` but no next occurrence of `start`:

```
start match the target if stop appears afterward without a next occurrence
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your regex like this:

```
(?<=start.*)target(?=(?:(?!start).)*stop)
```

This will fail the match if word `start` appears between `target` and `stop`.

`((?!start).)*` is a **negative lookahead** which means match 0 or more of any character (dot) if that character is **not** followed by `start` represented by `(?!start)`, then `((?!start).)*` is basically putting quantifier `*` after dot. So in short `.*` has been replaced by `((?!start).)*`

Comment: Thanks. Works great. Would you mind adding a bit of explanation regarding the `(?:(?!start).)*` bit that you've added, just to help me wrap my head around how it works?

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer.